# Does the jQuery css() method work with external stylesheet?

Tags: jquery, html, css, dom

I know that the jQuery `css()` method works with CSS rules set in a `<style>` tag or in the `style` attribute of an HTML element, but does it work with an external stylesheet?

For example if I have `<p id="test">` in my HTML file and in an external stylesheet this code:

```
#test {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Would `$("#test").css("visibility");` return `hidden`?

Comment: css() jq method returns the computed style

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `css()` method will read all the CSS properties on the specified element, no matter where or how they were set. So short answer, yes.

Comment: Including default property values provided by the user-agent stylesheet

Answer (score 1):

Yes, when you use `$("#test").css("visibility")` you are getting the value of visibility property.

If you want to set a value you can add the second parameter example:

```
$("#test").css("visibility","visible"); // setting visible to the visibility property
 // then if you test :
if($("#test").css("visibility") === "visible") // will return true;
```

It's a object that accept key and value.